# iframe for loading a contact form in a given page

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am using iframe to load my contact form in a given page, the page has some images. I use this code:

```html
<iframe src='my.php' frameborder='0'
width='100%' height='50' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
```

This code does work, but  I cannot see the part of the contact form, it goes up behind the the image.

I do no know how to bring the contact form up and see it completely. Currently it is not possible to fill in the form. Is there  any solution.

Thanks for your help

Comment: *"it goes up behind the image."* - you're going to have to elaborate on that. - CSS z-index?

Comment: Consider a page with an image on it, the most part of the contact form is not visible as it is located behind the image.

Comment: then it's a z-index issue, most likely.

Comment: Any comment to fix the issue

Comment: You are going to need to provide more concrete information about the html and css relating to the image and iframe. Also sounds like a css/html related question, and not a PHP question at all.

Comment: position:absolute;
   z-index:999;